# PowerShell: How to format a script that renames pdf's based on the number of rows in a csv file?

Tags: powershell, pdf

I have a PowerShell script that will rename the pdf's based on the name of a compressed (zipped) folder. Inside the compressed (zipped) folder is a excel (.csv) file.

For example:

The compressed (zipped) folder - 23579_ADV.zip (Contained excel (.csv) file - ADV_Mailer.csv)

The pdf's - ADVVPrintOutput_0001 & ADVVPrintOutput_0002

The end result - ADV_23579_Pr01_1-5000.pdf & ADV_23579_Pr02_5001-10000.pdf

The desired result since the contained csv has 8750 rows:

ADV_23579_Pr01_1-5000.pdf & ADV_23579_Pr02_5001-8750.pdf

The issue with the below PowerShell script is that the pdf names need to have the variable amount of rows that is contained in the excel (.csv) file.
The pdf names need to be broken down by 5000. Below it the script:

```
If (Test-Path D:\WORK\JetLetter\ABC\ABC_VL_Hot\*.zip) {
    $source=Get-ChildItem "D:\WORK\JetLetter\ABC\ABC_VL_Hot\*.zip" | select  -Last 1
    $JobID = "ABC_" + $source.BaseName.Split('_')[0]
    Echo $source.name
    Echo $JobID
    
    If (Test-Path ABCPrintOutput0001.pdf) {
        Rename-Item ABCPrintOutput0001.pdf "$($JobID)_Pr01_1-5000.pdf"
    }
    If (Test-Path ABCPrintOutput0002.pdf) {
        Rename-Item ABCPrintOutput0002.pdf "$($JobID)_Pr02_5001-10000.pdf"
    }
```

I found a command line that will count the rows. I just need a way to communicate the result to the Rename-Item.

```
Import-Csv *.csv | Measure-Object | Select-Object -expand count
```

Based on Dilly B's answer I reformatted the PowerShell script.

```
If (Test-Path D:\WORK\JetLetter\JWH\JWH_Tr_Hot\*.zip){

$source=Get-ChildItem "D:\WORK\JetLetter\JWH\JWH_Tr_Hot\*.zip" | select  -Last 1
Expand-Archive -Path *.zip -DestinationPath D:\WORK\JetLetter\JWH\JWH_Tr_Hot\
Rename-Item -Path "JWH_Mailer.csn" -NewName "JWH_Mailer.csv"
$csvFile = 'D:\WORK\JetLetter\JWH\JWH_Tr_Hot\JWH_Mailer.csv'
$lineCount = Import-Csv $csvFile | Measure-Object | Select-Object -expand count #Counting lines of a CSV File
$JobID = "JWH_" + $source.BaseName.Split('_')[0]
Echo $source.name
Echo $JobID


If (Test-Path JWHPrintOutput_0001.pdf){
    if( $lineCount -lt 5000 ){
        Rename-Item JWHPrintOutput_0001.pdf "$($JobID)_Pr01_1" + $lineCount + ".pdf"}
    elseif( $lineCount -gt 5000){
        Rename-Item JWHPrintOutput_0001.pdf "$($JobID)_Pr01_1-5000.pdf"}
}

If (Test-Path JWHPrintOutput_0002.pdf){
    if( $lineCount -lt 10000 ){
        Rename-Item JWHPrintOutput_0002.pdf "$($JobID)_Pr02_5001" + $lineCount + ".pdf"}
    elseif( $lineCount -gt 10000){
        Rename-Item JWHPrintOutput_0002.pdf "$($JobID)_Pr02_5001-10000.pdf"}
}
}
```

When I run the script it gives me the following error.

Expand-Archive : The path '' either does not exist or is not a valid file system path.
At D:\WORK\JetLetter\JWH\JWH_Tr\PrtOutpt_NameChange.ps1:4 char:1

- Expand-Archive -Path *.zip -DestinationPath D:\WORK\JetLetter\JWH\JWH ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:String) [Expand-Archive], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Expand-Archive
  ```

Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at 'JWH_Mailer.csn' does not exist.
At D:\WORK\JetLetter\JWH\JWH_Tr\PrtOutpt_NameChange.ps1:5 char:1

- Rename-Item -Path "JWH_Mailer.csn" -NewName "JWH_Mailer.csv"
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Rename-Item], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
  ```

134721_JWH.zip
JWH_134721

Comment: Hi, Could you please rewrite your question. Sorry! Its bit confusing with all CSV file and Zip file.

Comment: I have edited the question to explain the issue I am having in a better format.

Comment: Hi, I have two questions. 1. How are you reading CSV file in a zip folder without extracting it?  2.  Does this Zip file contains multiple PDF files with corresponding CSV files and how are you matching those names. or it contains only one PDF file along with one CSV File.

Comment: Hi, Dilly B. Thanks for the questions. Initially the script is only reading the name of the zip folder. Thinking ahead, a command would need to be added to extract the zip folder. Something like: Expand-Archive -LiteralPath. The zip file only contains a csv file. The pdf's to be renamed are located in a $SourceDir called "ABC_VL_9835". The source folder will have a variable amount of pdfs based on how many rows are in the csv file and broken out by 5000 rows.

Comment: Hi, @cnjfo672 From the error we can see that either the path is wrong or file does not exist. If you're looking for files please try Test-Path with -leaf or use Get-ChildItem with wildcard character and select the file you want to unzip. Also you can select your current working directory by using Set-Path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Dilly B, I was able to figure this one out. This is in a variable data printing atmosphere. It produces multible pdf's based on the art and mailing records.
The below PowerShell looks at the mailing list and renames the pdf's according to the number of records in the mailing list.

```
If (Test-Path D:\WORK\JetLetter\ABC\ABC_A001_Hot\*.zip){

$source=Get-ChildItem "D:\WORK\JetLetter\ABC\ABC_A001_Hot\*.zip" | select  -Last 1
Expand-Archive -Path D:\WORK\JetLetter\ABC\ABC_A001_Hot\*.Zip -DestinationPath D:\WORK\JetLetter\ABC\ABC_A001_Hot\ -Force
Rename-Item -Path "D:\WORK\JetLetter\ABC\ABC_A001_Hot\ABC_Mailer.csn" -NewName "D:\WORK\JetLetter\ABC\ABC_A001_Hot\ABC_Mailer.csv"
$csvFile = 'D:\WORK\JetLetter\ABC\ABC_A001_Hot\ABC_Mailer.csv'
$lineCount = Import-Csv $csvFile | Measure-Object | Select-Object -expand count #Counting lines of a CSV File
$JobID = "ABC_" + $source.BaseName.Split('_')[0]
Echo $source.name
Echo $JobID

If (Test-Path D:\WORK\JetLetter\ABC\ABC_A001_9835\ABCPrintOutput0001.pdf){
    if( $lineCount -lt 5000 ){
        Rename-Item ABCPrintOutput0001.pdf "$($JobID)_Pr01_1_$lineCount.pdf"}
    elseif( $lineCount -gt 5000){
        Rename-Item ABCPrintOutput0001.pdf "$($JobID)_Pr01_1-5000.pdf"}
}

If (Test-Path D:\WORK\JetLetter\ABC\ABC_A001_9835\ABCPrintOutput0002.pdf){
    if( $lineCount -lt 10000 ){
        Rename-Item ABCPrintOutput0002.pdf "$($JobID)_Pr02_5001_$lineCount.pdf"}
    elseif( $lineCount -gt 10000){
        Rename-Item ABCPrintOutput0002.pdf "$($JobID)_Pr02_5001-10000.pdf"}
}
}
Remove-Item D:\WORK\JetLetter\JWH\JWH_Tr_Hot\JWH_Mailer.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't still sure about how are you going to match your csv file and pdf file. I have given you a reference script for a one to one matching.

```
$csvFile = 'C:\PS\Sample-Spreadsheet-5000-rows.csv' #CSV file having 5000 lines
$pdfFile = 'C:\PS\Sample.pdf' # A PDF file
$pdfFileName = (Get-Item $pdfFile).BaseName #Get pdf file basename
$lineCount = Import-Csv $csvFile | Measure-Object | Select-Object -expand count #Counting lines of a CSV File

if(Test-Path $pdfFile){
    # Condition to check if linecount is lesser than equal to 5000
    if( $lineCount -lt 5000 ){
        Rename-Item $pdfFile "ABC_$($pdfFileName)_Pro01_1-5000.pdf"
    }
    # Condition to check if linecount is greater than equal to 5000 or lesser than equal to 10000
    elseif( ($lineCount -gt 5000) -and ($lineCount -lt 10000) ) {
        Rename-Item $pdfFile"ABC_$($pdfFileName)_Pro02_5001-10000.pdf"
    }
} else {  #If File Not found
    Write-Output "File Not Found"
}
```

If you have multiple PDF's and CSV's, then please use foreach and proceed.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi Dilly B. I appreciate the answer you provided. It did help me to understand the language a little bit better. I rewrote the script and placed it in my original question. However, I can't seem to figure out the error I am getting.